# Cleaners Rearranging My Desk

Tags: communication, negotiation

I work in a small company that has outside cleaners who come in every week and clean when the office is empty.

I tend to be working on a number of projects at once, so I can have different code books and other resources on my desk in addition to print outs and various other bits of paper that tend to have information that I only need for a day or two.

I have started to get complaints about this from the cleaners filtered through management, who may happen to be around when the cleaners are. Now I have worked to make my desk tidier, leaving books and paper and such in a pile, but some things like having my keyboard in front of me are just more convenient for me and don't look  any more "messy".

I am however still routinely getting my desk rearranged by the cleaners, I cant really say its tidier, it seems more of a passive aggressive thing now. In addition they have thrown out work and important notes that were left on my desk (we had to go dumpster diving to retrieve them). I asked my manager what to do and he said leave a note, I did but they just threw it away, now I am being told to leave a bigger note!

TLDR: How to stop cleaners rearranging my desk, they ignored a note.

Edit: they do speak English but may or may not have actually read the note I suppose.

Comment: If I were your manager I'd probably find another cleaning company. They have no business touching anything on the desks at all, let alone throwing things away. I suspect you'll have to get your manager to escalate this with them, since there's not much you can do from your position.

Comment: They only come in once a week? I wish ours would come in 2x per day.

Comment: Are you the only one who leaves things on your desk? If not, are you the only one that is having this problem?

Answer (score 14):

The best solution would be for your manager to talk to a manager in the cleaning organization about the issue, and get clear rules against the cleaners throwing away anything other than the contents of waste bins etc. Different people work best with different amounts of stuff on the desk, and the cleaning arrangements should allow for that.

A second best solution might be to get one or more desk stacking trays, and leave all your books and papers in there, at least on cleaning days. That would let you group together the materials for a given project, and pull them out as a unit when you are about to work on that project.

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing seems unreasonable. But most people - at least most people with practical jobs to do - are pretty reasonable if you actually talk to them. It might be they've been told to bin loose papers. It might be that what you're clearing away isn't what's causing problems for them. Find out more. If you can, have a conversation, and be prepared to listen, respect that they've got work to do just as much as you have.

Ask:

- which day(s) your desk is cleaned
- what items the cleaners are objecting to you leaving on your desk
- what this is causing them not to be able to do
- what places are appropriate for store these items (e.g. a spike for notes)

Show that you're willing to tidy you clutter so they can do their job and chances are, they will do their job in a way that doesn't inconvenience you either.

If you can't talk directly, you could go via your respective managers. In this case do it in writing so you get clear answers.

Answer (score 4):

It is beyond the pale for a cleaning crew to throw away anything on a desk, but I wouldn't mind if our cleaning crew dusted our desks every so often instead of just emptying the trash and vacuuming. Right now I have to keep a swiffer around and do it myself.

At our company, we have a fridge clean out policy where if you leave anything in there on the last Friday of the month, it gets tossed (although they clean out your containers and leave them on the counter).  Maybe a policy where you have to clear off your desk at the end of the week so the crew can dust would work? It sounds to me like the cleaners are required to do certain things,  and the state of your desk is making it difficult, so once a week might be a good compromise.

Comment: The policy that seems usual around here is that desks with papers on it remain untouched, clean desks (only the usual stuff of keyboard, mouse, etc. and maybe a single stack of paper) get cleaned.

Comment: Our cleaning staff used to clean exposed surfaces. If the desk was partly bare it got partly cleaned.  If it was buried, it was left for us to deal with.

Comment: @SJuan76 That makes sense to me also, but it seems like there may be a bit of a martinet heading up the cleaning crew in this case. Throwing away papers with notes on them seems like a malicious act to make a point. On the other hand,  I never put anything irreplaceable on a piece of paper on my desk. I might have printouts of digital information with scribbles, but I would never leave hardcopy out that I'd have to dumpster dive for.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live?  Cleaning people may not speak your language or may not be able to read.  I am in the US and we had a box marked garbage that did not get taken away.  A guy wrote basura on it and it was gone the next day.

Speak your language or not they should not be throwing anything on a desk away.

Comment: We always write Trash / Basura on boxes that need to go.  Sometimes they speak english, sometimes they speak spanish.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange since everyone sets their desk up the way they want it, it's more important to have people work effectively then it is to set a standard for how desks are cleaned and since your manager says 'leave a note' I doubt there are any requirements to begin with.

There are a number of possibilities of issues

- The cleaners may have been 'yelled' at or 'scolded' for inproper cleaning (which may have been BS to begin with from an employee that likes to complain and cause trouble for people) and they are trying to take this out on the company through you, or making ABSOLUTELY sure there is NOTHING that can come back to them.

If this is the case, find a way to keep your stuff organized and portable (messenger bag, brief case, etc...)

- You're not telling us the whole story and you have actually left some messes that have caused the cleaners problems. It's very unlikely the cleaners would jeopardize their job just to get at a random employee they don't know, don't care about, or doesn't affect them in some way - so it sounds like there may actually be another problem. Maybe you left that note saying something vulgar or cruel to the cleaners, big mistake - just the same way you don't insult the people who are serving you food.

Apologize to the cleaners, they deserve respect to - leave them a nice gift or something and make up for the mistake (not saying you did this, but if you did this is how you would fix it). Write an apologetic letter that also explains what your situation with your desk is and needs to be, that you were just frustrated, whatever it may be...

- Political nonsense and the manager doesn't want or can't deal with it and/or is lieing to you

Again, keep something portable around. Also look into the company and the rules, talk to HR first and foremost they are the ones that make sure you are able to do your job without social issues complicating them, find out from HR if there are other problems like this etc...